# Parsing string with reference to series of numbers - shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

This is my input file **input.gz** where *NN*NNNNNNNNNN is totally random and is unknown. It has values from 0 to 9.

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA]  
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA some random text
zzzzzzzzzzzz xxxxxxxx yy]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA]
```

In the 8th row as shown below, the string in last column is extended to the next line. This is just an example. The string may be extended to next line in other rows too.

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *NN*NNNNNNNNNN [AAAAA some random text
zzzzzzzzzzzz xxxxxxxx yy]
```

Let's take an example:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *18*6666666666 [AAAAA]  
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *11*2222222222 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *18*6666666666 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *11*2222222222 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *11*2222222222 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *15*9999999999 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *11*2222222222 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *11*2222222222 [AAAAA some random text
zzzzzzzzzzzz xxxxxxxx yy]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *13*7777777777 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *19*5555555555 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *10*4444444444 [AAAAA]
```

I took all the NNNNNNNNNN as the same number for better understanding.

I need a script using SED or AWK or GREP which shows up only uniq NNNNNNNNNN having the string AAAAA. The last coloumn may have some other string too. But it must have AAAAA either in first line or next line.

Please ignore all other constraints like yyyy-mm-dd or hh:mm:ss. The only constraints to be considered are ***NN*NNNNNNNNNN** and **AAAAA**

Expected output should be:

```
*11*2222222222 
*10*4444444444  
*19*5555555555  
*18*6666666666  
*13*7777777777  
*15*9999999999
```

As the last column in 8th row is extended to next line too, I guess using AWK is ruled out?
How to properly implement script like this way? (If this is wrong, other way is fine too)

```
grep "\[AAAA"|sed -n '/\*[0-9]*\*[0-9]*/p'
```

**Please remember that *NN*NNNNNNNNNN is totally random so we can't take any value for reference while using grep or sed.**

Comment: Is the `string` a constant length in all lines? Also, is the wrap-around actually a newline, or does it just show up that way on your terminal?

Comment: Good definition of your problem but you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Think about using `]` as the RS value and of course, piping your `awk` output to `sort -u` (`man sort`). Good luck.

Comment: @AustinHastings Yeah. The column showing as string us constant. Actually there are multiple columns. I just posted few for better understanding. If you are talking about AAAAA, it's not constant. But the series of strings should have AAAAA. And it is a new line I guess (I've extended the terminal in a wide screen monitor and it's still showing in a new line). Sorry, I'm still in learning phase of scripting. Not sure how to find out if it's a new line other way.

Comment: There's a few things that might make his problem difficult (some lines that don't have `AAAAA` in the expected column, some that have `AAAAA` but in the wrong column, some that have blanks in `string`, some that have `AAAAA` in the expected column but after a newline). [edit] your sample input/output to include some of those cases so we get a better understanding of your requirements because it'd be trivial to write a script that produces the expected output given the input you've shows us so far (e.g see the current answers) but then it'd almost certainly fail when run against your real data.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` + `sort -u` solution:

```
zcat input.gz | sed  -n 's/.* \(\*[0-9]*\*[0-9]*\) \[AAAAA\].*/\1/p' | sort -u
*10*4444444444
*11*2222222222
*13*7777777777
*15*9999999999
*18*6666666666
*19*5555555555
```

Answer (score 1):

This, using GNU awk for multi-char RS, is **probably** what you want:

```
$ awk -v RS='][[:blank:]]*\n' '/[^]]*AAAAA[^]]*$/ && !seen[$4]++{print $4}' file
*18*6666666666
*11*2222222222
*15*9999999999
*13*7777777777
*19*5555555555
*10*4444444444
```

If not then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input and expected output. For example I THINK you might want to handle:

```
$ cat file
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *10*2222222222 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AAAAA *18*6666666666 [xxxxx]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *11*3333333333 [some random text
AAAAA zzzzzzzzzzzz xxxxxxxx yy]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *12*5555555555 [some
random
AAAAA text across
multiple
lines zzzzzzzzzzzz xxxxxxxx yy]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *13*7777777777 [BBBBB]
```

as:

```
$ awk -v RS=']\n' '/[^]]*AAAAA[^]]*$/ && !seen[$4]++{print $4}' file
*10*2222222222
*18*6666666666
*11*3333333333
*12*5555555555
```

If so try it with the other answers you get.

wrt the statement in your question `As the last column in 8th row is extended to next line too, I guess using AWK is ruled out?` - completely the reverse. grep and sed are line-based, awk is the only standard UNIX tool that is instead record-based.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
pattern="AAAAA"
zcat input.gz \
| grep '\['"$pattern"'[] ]' \
| sed -e 's/^.*\(\*[0-9*]*\).*$/\1/' \
| sort -u
```